# Nginx reverse proxy with different subdomains, config file NOT WORKING

Tags: nginx, proxy

I have a setup involving the following domains:

- site.com
- abc.site.com
- xyz.site.com

And the following two servers:

- 12.34.56.78
- 98.76.54.32

Basically, I am trying to shape my traffic as followed: CloudFlare -> 98.76.54.32 -> 12.34.56.78. So, the 98 IP acts as a reverse proxy, and the 12 IP acts as the destination/main server.

On CloudFlare I have all of these domains pointed to the reverse proxy server. The reverse proxy is running this configuration file, `reverse-prox.conf`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_tokens off;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://12.34.56.78;
    }
}
```

Now, on the main server, 12.34.56.78, I have the following configuration files:

**abc.site.com**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/abc;

    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name abc.site.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri;
    }
}
```

**xyz.site.com**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/xyz;

    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name xyz.site.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri;
    }
}
```

I shortened the configuration files for convenience, but that's the gist of it.

It works near-flawlessly, but there is a problem. abc.site.com works correctly, but xyz.site.com shows the /abc/ folder instead of the /xyz/ folder. Not sure why this happens. There is no default configuration in either of the Nginx configurations (on both servers).

So, how do I fix this? Why does abc.site.com work correctly, but xyz.site.com display the same thing as abc.site.com (instead of its respective /xyz/ contents).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does abc.site.com work correctly, but xyz.site.com display the same thing as abc.site.com (instead of its respective /xyz/ contents).

Use [`proxy_set_header`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_set_header) to pass `Host` request header from `98.76.54.32` to `12.34.56.78`. By default, [nginx doesn't](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/#headers) proxy this `Host` header.

nginx sets `Host` request header to [`$proxy_host`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#var_proxy_host) variable, which is the hostname/IP address and port set on your [`proxy_pass`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#var_proxy_host) directive.

For example, on `98.76.54.32`:

> ```
> server {
>     listen 80;
>     server_tokens off;
>
>     location / {
>         proxy_set_header Host $host;
>         proxy_pass http://12.34.56.78;
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Worked, thank you! I was about to just use multiple ports, but this method is way easier. Thanks so much!